# How would you use a loop to print an ordered list?

Tags: python

How would I get this to print an ordered list so if I entered kiwi, dog, cat, it would print

```
cat
kiwi 
dog
```

Here is the code I have:

```
    input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by comma:")
lisp = input_string. split(',')
for i in lisp:
    if 'cat' == i:
        print ('cat')
    elif 'kiwi' == i:
        print ('kiwi')
    else:
        print (i)
```

Here is what it produces:

kiwi
 dog
 cat

[Updated the code] 
I know how to use the sort method to alphabetize, but I need the list to be in a certain order with the random words (ex.dog) just added at the bottom. I am not a coder, and am not a student, I am trying to just learn. So I appreciate all help, all approaches, and your patience.

Comment: Why not just `print(i)`?

Comment: Try to research yourself before asking questions

Comment: I don't understand what method you'd like to apply to sort the list, could you expand on how you'd want to sort this list?

Comment: @coiax he is not sorting  it .

Comment: instead of `if 'cat' in lisp:` use `if 'cat'==i :`

Comment: If you have decided a priori what are the words you have to print and in what order then just make a check of the input words to see if they are the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

just do :

```
input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by comma")
lisp = input_string. split(',')
print(sorted(lisp))

input:
[c,b,a]

output:
[a,b,c]
```

the "sorted" method sorts elements. you can specify the sort method if you wish.

```
e.g:
sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])
```

Comment: I know how to use the sort method to alphabetize, but I want to sort it using a specific order thats NOT alphabetical.

Comment: then use the example, set up a key and then use sorted. more here : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted

check example 3. it defines a custom sort function and passes that in to the key flag

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to print your list in order except that `"cat"` and `"kiwi"` should be moved to the front. This would have worked:

```
lisp = ['kiwi', 'cat', 'dog']

if 'cat' in lisp:
    print('cat')
if 'kiwi' in lisp:
    print('kiwi')
for i in lisp:
    if i not in ('cat', 'kiwi'):
         print(i)
```

Output:

```
cat
kiwi
dog
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment from my first answer. set up a key and then use sorted. more here : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted

check example 3. it defines a custom sort function and passes that in to the key flag:

```
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# random list
random = [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]

# sort list with key
sortedList = sorted(random, key=takeSecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

This snipit of code prints the values in the list sorted by the third character.  This is an example of using a lambda function to do your bidding.  Remember that a sort is a potentially destructive function.  If you want to preserve the original list, you should enclose it in a copy-list function.

```
(loop for an ele in (sort '("cat" "kiwi" "dog")
                          #'(lambda (x y) (char-lessp (elt x 2) (elt y 2))))
      do (print ele))
```